# Taylor series of $\frac 1 {1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have to construct the Taylor series of
$$\frac 1 {1+x^2}$$

around $0$ and $1$ and analyze the convergence in both cases. Also (but this is a consequence of the previous series) I have to construct the Taylor series of

$$arctan(x)$$

What I have so far:

- I know that the Taylor polynomial around $0$ of $\frac 1 {1+x^2}$ is $$1-x^2+x^4-x^6+....+(-1)^nx^{2n}$$
- If I have the power series of a function f such as $F'=f$, I can construct the power series of $F$ with $F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {a_n} {n+1} (x-a)^{n+1}$

Comment: Recall that the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 -...$. So $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - ...$. Then, we have that $\text{atan}(x) = \int (1-x^2+x^4 - ...) dx = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1} / (2n+1)!$. Strictly speaking, one should be rigourous here, but i) it is clear that $x^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and ii) there are proofs abound on $\sum \int = \int \sum$; there is a good one in Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: To further my comment above, note that it is easier to manipualate a Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and then substitute as appropriate to get the corresponding one for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$; this should make the computation much less computationally intensive for the expansion at $x=1$.

Comment: I'm working with that book actually, but I don´t get the factorial in $(2n+1)$, and I don´t get why I can extend so easily the Taylor polynomial to the Taylor series... And other thing I´m still missing the series around 1 and not 0

Comment: I made a mistake; there is no factorial. It is simply $(2n+1)$. You are quite correct; I was going too fast.

Comment: If I work with $\frac 1 {1+x}$, shouldn't I use $log$?

Comment: Spivak actually proves that you can find the Taylor expansion for $\frac{1}{1+u}$ and then substitute $u=x^2$. It is easier to derivate $\frac{1}{1+x}$ than $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and you need to do this to find the expansion about $x=1$.

Comment: It's okay! I'm just trying to understand too much too fast, and getting confused, that's why I'm going slow with this. A question, if you don't mind, if I have the Taylor polynomial, does that mean that I have the Taylor series? I only need to 'extend' the sum to infinite? Do I need more theoretical justification?

Comment: Yes, the Taylor series just extends the Taylor polynomial to infinity. It is an exact expression for any analytic function; it includes the error term.

Comment: But it's not necessarily equal to the original function right? Doesn't the error term have to converge to zero for that? Thanks so much for your help, by the way.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of analytic; that the Taylor polynomials converge to function or in other words, the error term converges to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have the power series of a function f such as $F'=f$, I can construct the power series of $F$ with $F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {a_n} {n+1} (x-a)^{n+1}$

Have you tried this?  Note that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

You have the power series for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ centered at $0$, for which 
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{n/2} & n \text{ is even}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

In order to find the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ at $1$, note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2 + 1} &= 
\frac{1}{1 + (1+(x-1))^2} = 
\frac{1}{1 + 1 + 2(x-1) + (x-1)^2}
\\ &
= \frac{1}{2 + 2(x-1) + (x-1)^2}
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \left[(x-1) + \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right]}
\\ &
= \frac 12 \left(1 - \left[(x-1) + \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right] + \left[(x-1) + \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right]^2 - \cdots \right)
\\ &
= \frac 12 - \frac 12 (x-1) + \frac 14(x-1)^2 \\
&\qquad- \frac 18 (x-1)^4 + \frac 18 (x-1)^5 -\frac 1{16} (x-1)^6\\
&\qquad+ \frac 1{32} (x-1)^8 - \frac 1{32} (x-1)^9 + \frac 1{64}(x-1)^{10} - \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That´s why I wrote that. I need the power series for $\frac 1 {1+x^2}$ first, around both 0 and 1, and I can't find $a_n$...

Comment: You're looking for $a_{n}$, but you have it; what are the coefficients for the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: You are right, but the problem is that those coefficients are already divided by the factorial, which in the theorem is not included, so I'll probably have to adjust that. And that's it? If I have the Taylor expansion, then I immediately have the Taylor series?

Comment: Yes, that is it.